# real analysis limit problem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $1 \leq p < \infty$. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and has compact support and let $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $f_t(x) = f(x-t).$

Prove: $\lim_{t \to 0} ||f-f_t||_p = 0$.

Edit: I already got the answer. I'll post it as a formal answer soon!

Comment: Trivial observation: You should probably say something about $p=\infty$.

Comment: oh sorry. p is also assumed to be finite. i'll edit that

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is nearly right.

You only need to insert at the appropriate place that $f$ is uniformly continuous so that you can select $δ$ independent of $x_0$.

You can also connect $N$ more explicitly to the support of $f$, so that not only the difference, but the function values themselves are zero.

Comment: why is it uniformly continuous?

Comment: Because its support is compact.

Comment: oh is that something trivial? i dont see how it would follows immediately. can you show how?

Comment: For $ϵ>0$ there is a $δ(x_0)$ for every point $x_0$ so that $f(B(x_0, δ(x_0))\subset B(f(x_0),ϵ/2)$. The balls $B(x,δ(x))$ obviously cover the entire compact support. Thus there is a finite covering, take $δ=\min(δ(x_1),…,δ(x_n))$, then $f(B(x,δ))\subset B(f(x),ϵ)$ uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use dominated convergence theorem.

Clearly, $|f-f_{t}|$ is bounded by $2M$ if we let $|f|\leq M$ and of course $2M$ is in $L^p$.
And $f-f_{t}$ converges to 0 with respect to $t$.
So the convergence theorem implies that $\|f-f_{t}\|_{p}$ goes to 0.

Comment: How are you sure f is bounded?

Comment: @lanturn image of continuous function on compact set is compact.